# How do you create a loop using two dynamic variables?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple cells ("positions") that require particular interior colors and values.
Each of these cells is associated with its own corresponding cell in another worksheet.

At the moment I have about 35 of these positions, but I may have 150 in the future, so adding these manually would be tedious! This is the code I have at the moment:

```
Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
Dim Secondsheet As Worksheet
Dim position1 As Range
Dim position2 As Range
Dim position3 As Range
Dim lnCol As Long

Set FirstSheet As ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FirstSheet")
Set SecondSheet As ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SecondSheet")
Set position1 = Firstsheet.Range("G11")
Set position2 = Firstsheet.Range("F11")
Set Position3 = Firstsheet.Range("E11")
lnCol = 'this is a column number which is found earlier in the sub.

position1.Interior.Color = SecondSheet.Cells(8, lnCol).Interior.Color
position2.Interior.Color = SecondSheet.Cells(9, lnCol).Interior.Color
position3.Interior.Color = SecondSheet.Cells(10, lnCol).Interior.Color
position1.Offset(2, 0).Value = SecondSheet.Cells(8, lnCol).Value
position2.Offset(2, 0).Value = SecondSheet.Cells(9, lnCol).Value
position3.Offset(2, 0).Value = SecondSheet.Cells(10, lnCol).Value
```

Ideally, I would like a loop that would use two arrays that change at the same time, but I have no idea how to make it work! This is an example of what I would like to see:

```
For Each PositionVar In Array(position1, position2, position3)
    PositionVar.Interior.Color = dynamicvariable.Interior.Color
    PositionVar.Offset(2,0).Value = dynamicvariable.Value
Next PositionVar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have now got to the following, but I am now getting a type mismatch...  `PositionArray = Array(position1, position2, position3)
SecondSheetArray = Array(xposition1, xposition2, xposition3)
Dim i As Variant

For Each i In PositionArray
    PositionArray(i).Interior.Color = SecondSheetArray(i).Interior.Color
    PositionArray(i).Offset(2, 0).Value = SecondSheetArray(i).Value
Next i`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use two loops stacked together to solve this? For example:

```
for each rng in Array(Range1, Range2, Range3)
    for each position in rng
       'Do whatever you like with this Range
    next position
next rng
```

Comment: Hi @Steffen, thanks for the answer. I think the problem with this would be that I want **position1** to act  only with **range1**. I think the above code would loop so **Range1** would also act with **position1, position2,** and **position3**..

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, LastColumn As Long, Counter As Long, lnCol As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Counter = 8
    lnCol = 3 'Change value

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Set the sheet with positions
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Set the second sheet
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With ws1
        'Find the LastColumn of row 11
        LastColumn = .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Loop from the last column until column 5th
        For i = LastColumn To 5 Step -1

            With .Cells(11, i)
                .Interior.Color = ws2.Cells(Counter, lnCol).Interior.Color
                .Offset(2, 0).Value = ws2.Cells(Counter, lnCol).Value
            End With

            Counter = Counter + 1

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**NOTE**
The limitation of using Last column is that if there is no values in row 11 you should use a variable instead of last column referring to the total value of column you want

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find an answer by using arrays and a control variable. You just need to ensure that the corresponding variables are in the same order!. Hope this helps others.

```
Dim PositionArray As Variant
Dim SecondSheetArray As Variant
Dim i As Variant 

PositionArray = Array(position1, position2, position3) 
SecondSheetArray = Array(SecondSheet1, SecondSheet2, SecondSheet3) 

For i = 0 To UBound(PositionArray)
    PositionArray(i).Interior.Color = OverviewArray(i).Interior.Color
    PositionArray(i).Offset(2, 0).Value = OverviewArray(i).Value
Next i
```